# What are advantages and disadvantages of having a daemon/network service listen on a port less than 1024?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

What happens if I launch a service with port < 1024. I know we cannot use ports less than 1024 as all these ports are being used by system services.

Will I have an edge if I use the ports 1-1023?

Answer (score 2):

Your title and question do not really match. Some services block the list of [well-known-ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports), some don't. If your service tries to bind to a WKP and it is unoccupied, it will work (but needs superuser-rights on unix like systems). So you *can* use them in a non-standard way, but really shouldn't. But if you create your own HTTP service, for example,  you are expected to use port 80 (and/ or 443, 8080, etc.).